# Oracle ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to do an insert from a XML column to a CLOB column and I end up with this error.

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small

Any ideeas of what i can do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the code, it is difficult to be sure. I suspect somewhere you are going via a VARCHAR2 and exceeding either 4000 characters or 32000 characters (depending on whether it is working through SQL or PL/SQL).
DB version may help

Comment: Thank you for your response, I figured out in the end, actually I wanted to convert XML to CLOB and did it with toCLOB() function and it spit this error, but when doing it with getCLOB() it worked.